# In what programming language is Python's regex module written in?

Tags: programming-languages, regular-expressions

If I try to rewrite specific regex functionalities (e.g. substituting a string) in Python, a solution using the regex module is always faster.

Is regex written in C?

Comment: It sounds like you think Python's regex implementation is not written in Python.  You're probably right.  Next question?

Comment: A regex engine can be written in any language. In the case of Python's `re` module, the regex engine is indeed written in C.

Comment: @amon: Actually, as I just found out, that is untrue for almost all Python implementations and only half true even for CPython. IronPython simply uses the CLI's `System.Text.RegularExpressions`, Jython uses a compiler written in Python which compiles to byte code for a VM written in Java, PyPy uses a compiler written in Python which compiles to byte code for a VM written in RPython, and CPython uses a compiler written in Python which compiles to byte code for a VM written in C.

Comment: I am not voting to delete this question, though it is clearly off-topic, because of @JörgWMittag's interesting answer. But I would not vote for reopen it, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regex is a language. It doesn't look like much of one, but it is.

Like every language, it is not written in anything. A language is a set of mathematical rules and restrictions. If we can say that it is written in anything *at all*, we would probably say that it is written in English. (Or in a specific English-based jargon for specifying languages, enriched with graphical and mathematical tools for expressing language rules.)

A specific *implementation* of the language (regex) is of course written in a specific language, but the language itself isn't.

As an example, the implementation of the `re` module that ships as part of the CPython implementation of the Python programming language is called the *Secret Labs' Regular Expression Engine (sre)*, and is written in Python and C. More precisely, it consists of [a *compiler* written in Python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/sre_compile.py) that compiles `re` regexes into byte code for a virtual machine, and [a VM written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_sre/sre.c) that interprets that byte code.

The implementation that ships with [Jython](https://jython.org/) uses [the same Python code and byte code](https://hg.python.org/jython/file/tip/Lib/sre_compile.py), but [the byte code VM is written in Java](https://hg.python.org/jython/file/tip/src/org/python/modules/sre), not C.

At first glance, IronPython *looks* similar: [compiler in Python](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Src/StdLib/Lib/sre_compile.py) and [VM in C#](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/_sre.cs). However, if you look closer, the VM is actually a non-functional stub, and [the *real* implementation is in C#](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/re.cs) and is based on [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions) from the CLI.

[PyPy](https://pypy.org/) follows the standard pattern again: [compiler in Python](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/blob/branch/default/lib-python/2.7/sre_compile.py) and [the VM in RPython](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/blob/branch/default/pypy/module/_sre/interp_sre.py).

And of course other languages have completely different flavors of regex. E.g. [Ruby's `Regexp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) is quite different from [Python's `re`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html). And in Ruby, we have similar diversity: [YARV](http://www.atdot.net/yarv/) uses an engine called [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) to implement its `Regexp` class whereas [JRuby](https://jruby.org/) uses [joni](https://github.com/jruby/joni).